# Preventing reboots when (not) editing grub file

Tags: salt-stack

I want to apply some kernel parameters to the /etc/defaul/grub with salt. When I applied the parameters I need to do a grub_update + shutdown -r to the minion. If not, I don't want the minion to update/restart.

So far I have this .sls:

```yaml
edit_grub_config:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/default/grub
    - pattern: '^(GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT="[^"]*)(")'
    - repl: '\1 spectre_v2=on spec_store_bypass_disable=on tsx=off tsx_async_abort=full,nosmt mds=full,nosmt l1tf=full,force nosmt=force kvm.nx_huge_pages=force\2'
    - unless: grep -q "spectre_v2=on spec_store_bypass_disable=on tsx=off tsx_async_abort=full,nosmt mds=full,nosmt l1tf=full,force nosmt=force kvm.nx_huge_pages=force" /etc/default/grub

grub_update:
  cmd.run:
    - name: update-grub
    - require:
      - file: edit_grub_config

restart_minion:
  cmd.run:
    - name: shutdown -r now
    - require:
      - cmd: grub_update
```

Now when I apply it multiple times, it does not add the string to the grub file multiple times, so edit_grub_config works as intended. But it always does restarts. My goal is not to have restarts when nothing was added to the grub file.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution:

```
edit_grub_config:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/default/grub
    - pattern: '^(GRUB_CMD_LINUX_DEFAULT="[^"]*)(")'
    - repl: '\1 spectre_v2=on spec_store_bypass_disable=on tsx=off tsx_async_abort=full,nosmt mds=full,nosmt l1tf=full,force nosmt=force kvm.nx_huge_pages=force\2'
    - unless: grep -q "spectre_v2=on spec_store_bypass_disable=on tsx=off tsx_async_abort=full,nosmt mds=full,nosmt l1tf=full,force nosmt=force kvm.nx_huge_pages=force" /etc/default/grub

grub_update:
  cmd.run:
    - name: update-grub
    - onchanges:
      - file: /etc/default/grub

restart_minion:
  cmd.run:
    - name: shutdown -r now
    - watch:
      - cmd: grub_update
    - onchanges:
      - file: /etc/default/grub
```